# Ramsey Number Inequality: $R(\underbrace{3,3,...,3,3}_{k+1}) \le (k+1)(R(\underbrace{3,3,...3}_k)-1)+2$

Tags: combinatorics, inequality, graph-theory, ramsey-theory

I want to prove that:

$$R(\underbrace{3,3,...,3,3}_{k+1}) \le (k+1)(R(\underbrace{3,3,...3}_k)-1)+2$$

where R is a Ramsey number. In the LHS, there are $k+1$ $3$'s, and in the RHS, there are $k$ $3's$. I really have no clue how to start this proof. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: As dumb as it sounds, have you tried induction? It becomes a case study for something simpler like $R(3,3,3)$ and should follow through for higher cases.

Comment: That does seem like it would be good, but I'm very poor with induction.

Comment: I strongly suggest that you get better with induction.

Comment: @ MJD: You're probably right!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The general strategy will probably look something like this.  (Let $R =  R(\underbrace{3,\ldots,3}_k)$ in what follows.)

1. Take $k+1$ copies of $K_{R-1}$, the complete graph on $R-1$ vertices, and assume that the edges of  each one are colored with $k+1$ colors so as to avoid monochromatic triangles.
2. Then suppose that no copy contains a triangle in the $k+1$'th color.
3. Then show that if you add 2 more vertices $u,v$ there must be some monochromatic triangle unless (something about the edges between $u$ and the $K_{R-1}$'s, and between $v$ and the $K_{R-1}$'s).
4. Then show that the edge from $u$ to $v$ must complete a monochromatic triangle with some vertex in one of the $K_{R-1}$'s.

A more careful analysis would consider the many edges between one $K_{R-1}$ and another, but with any luck you won't have to do that.

On review, I think Alex's suggestion of induction on $k$ is probably an excellent one.

Comment: Perfect! thank you for the help. It's very clear now what to do!