# Existence of a monochromatic triangle

Tags: graph-theory, ramsey-theory

I have recently learned about Ramsey Theory and I think that sometimes in some olympiads problem it may be a really powerful technique, for example in this problem:

> A magician has $66$ potions. Two potions when react can generate $4$
>   different effect. Prove that there exist $3$ potions $A,B,C$ such that the
>   reactions $A-B , A-C, B-C$ generate the same effect

I thought that if we consider a connected graph with $66$ nodes, the problem is isomorphic to show that there exist a monochromatic triangle in this graph. So the problem is equivalent to show(or at least I think) that:  $$R(3,0,0,0)\leq 66\ \ \ \ $$            Are there some useful upper bounds for generalized Ramsey Numbers?      :)

Comment: I'm not sure what the notation $R(3,0,0,0)$ means here. I would denote the Ramsey number here by $R(3,3,3,3)$ or possibly $R(3;4)$ and if you're one of those weird people who use arrow notation, you could also write $66 \to (3)_4$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are, yes.

Specifically for Ramsey numbers for monochromatic triangles, the result you need follows directly from the inequality proved [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/314013) that $$R(\underbrace{3,3,\dots,3,3}_{k+1}) \le (k+1)(R(\underbrace{3,3,\dots,3}_k)-1)+2.$$ Since we know $R(3,3) = 6$, we can apply this inequality once to conclude that $R(3,3,3) \le 3 \cdot 5 + 2 = 17$ and then apply it again to conclude that $R(3,3,3,3) \le 4 \cdot 16 + 2 = 66$.

The number $R(3,3,3,3)$ is exactly the bound needed in this question: if we draw a graph whose vertices are potions, and color each edge according to the reaction produced by the vertices it joins, then we have a $4$-colored complete graph $K_{66}$, and what we're looking for is exactly a monochromatic triangle.